# ionic build ios successful but ionic build ios --release failed

Tags: ios, ionic2

I am using ionic2 to develop in-house mobile app. I can build ios successful with:

```
ionic build ios and
ionic build ios --prod
```

but it kept failing, when I do

```
ionic build ios --release
```

Here is the error message:

```
Check dependencies

Code Signing Error: CMLookup has conflicting provisioning settings. CMLookup is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'



** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

So I open the project in xcode, unchecked the **automatically manage signing**, checked it back, re-selected the Team (development team) but it still doesn't help.  I went to xcode project **build setting** in the **signing** section, to make sure all the settings in **Code Signing Identity** are set to **iOS developer**.

I also tried

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
```

but I still kept getting the signing error above when I did **ionic build ios --release**

I don't know what else I should try now.. Please help. Thank you!!

PS: My ionic info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 8.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.9.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 3.1.7-201801172029
ios-deploy version: 1.9.2 
ios-sim version: 6.1.2 
OS: macOS
Node Version: v8.9.1
Xcode version: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

George

Comment: did you try this  this command **ionic cordova build ios --prod --release**

Comment: Yes.  I tried that many times.  Thank you.. ionic cordova build ios --prod --release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird, but I simply disconnected my iphone from mac, so xcode has no change to detect the connected iphone while running ionic build ios --release.

It was worth to remove ios from platform and add it back.

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
```

It was worth also to uncheck the **automatically manage signing**, checked it back, re-selected the Team (development team). And go to xcode project build setting in the signing section, to make sure all the settings in Code Signing Identity are set to iOS developer.

Comment: Same error. Build succeeded after unplugging iPhone from USB port.